# "aapt tool failed" , "values.xml:3: error: Found tag id where item is expected"

Tags: android-studio, actionscript-3, apk, android-app-bundle, distriqt

aapt tool failed:C:\Users[my_pc_name]\AppData\Local\Temp\129bc340-6df9-460a-b47b-694a3b23548e\savedstate-1.1.0-res\values\values.xml:3: error: Found tag id where item is expected

Hello I am using ANES DISTRIQT , AS3 , Harman SDK, VS-Code in this development.

I tried 33.1.-935 and the new version 50.0.1.1  still , this error always pop up.

Any advice or help for this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the legacy build method. You need to update to the latest build method.

https://github.com/airsdk/Adobe-Runtime-Support/discussions/1782